# c++ how can i change a char of a file using fstream with [] operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, fstream

Hello i got an assignment to use the operator[] to change a char in a txt file with fstream.
to get the char i used this:

```
char File::operator[](int index)
{
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i <= index; ++i)
    {
        ifs.get(c);
    }
    return c;
}
```

now i made a function that replaces the char in the file without []:

```
void Change(ifstream& ifs, int index, char ch)
{
    ofstream ofs("D:\\temp.txt");
    char c;
    while (ifs.get(c))
    {
        ofs.put(c);
    }
    ofs = ofstream("D:\\test.txt", ios_base::trunc);
    ifs = ifstream("D:\\temp.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        ifs.get(c);
        ofs.put(c);
    }
    ifs.get(c);
    ofs.put(ch);
    while (ifs.get(c))
    {
        ofs.put(c);
    }
    remove("D:\\temp.txt");
}
```

if you have an idea please post it i cant think of a way to solve this. now there is a hint with the assinment and that is you need to use a object to change. so basiclly i cant understand how to allow:

```
File f("D:\\test.txt");
f[0] = 'y';
```

and the file class is defined this way:

```
class File
{
public:
    File(string loc) :loc(loc), ifs(loc, ios_base::in) {}
    char operator[](int index);
    ~File();
private:
    string loc;
    ifstream ifs;
};
```

Comment: the question is how to solve this problem.

Comment: What "problem" would that be? If you're asking for someone to write the entire code for you, that's not going to happen. Otherwise, you need to explain exactly what your problem is with the shown code.

Comment: im not asking someone to write me the entire code im asking to explain to me how to do f[0] = 'y'

Comment: Ok, that's much more clearer. You should edit your question, and make this a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you require `operator[]` to return a reference that you can then assign your character to and that will manipulate the file:

```
'something'& operator[](int index);
```

As you can't return a reference to a character held in a file, you'll need to return a reference to a class ('something') that can carry out the operation for you when you invoke its `operator=(char)`. As a bonus, you can also include a char conversion operator to read the character too (`operator char()`).

Here's this explanation in code form:

```
class FileCharProxy
{
    public:
        FileCharProxy(std::iostream& stream, int index) : stream(stream), index(index) { }
        operator char() const
        {
            stream.seekg(index);
            char ch = stream.get();
            return ch;
        }
        FileCharProxy& operator=(char ch)
        {
            stream.seekp(index);
            stream.put(ch);
            return *this;
        }
    private:
        std::iostream& stream;
        int index;
};

class File
{
    public:
        File(std::string loc) :loc(loc), fs(loc) {}
        FileCharProxy operator[](int index)
        {
            return FileCharProxy { fs, index };
        }
    private:
        std::string loc;
        std::fstream fs;
};
```

You can call it like this:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &s, FileCharProxy &p)
{
    s << static_cast<char>(p);
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    File myfile("modify_file.data");

    auto ch = myfile[2];
    std::cout << "Character was: " << ch << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Character will be: " << static_cast<char>(ch + 1) << std::endl;

    myfile[2] = myfile[2] + 1;
}
```

Comment: it enters the edit function but when i try to edit the file it doesnt change and the project doesnt crash but doesnt work properly

Comment: It seems to work for me
    $ cat modify_file.data ; ./modify_file ; cat modify_file.data
    abcdefghi
    Character was: c
    Character will be: d
    abddefghi

Comment: can you try it on a text file?

Answer (score 3):

The usual way is to define a helper class:

```
class assignment_helper {

   char v;
   size_t i;
   File *p;

public:

   assignment_helper(char v_, size_t i_, File *p_) : v(v_), p(p_), i(i_) {}

   operator char() const { return v; }

   assignment_helper &operator=(char new_char)
   {
       p->Change(i, new_char);
       return *this;
   }
};
```

And your `[]` operator then returns this helper class, instead of a plain `char`.

```
assignment_helper operator[](size_t index);
```

So, when this is used in an assignment operation:

```
file[10]='x';
```

The `operator[]` returns an instance of this helper class, and the `=` invokes its assignment operator, with the character to assign as a parameter, and the `operator=` forwards this parameter to a `put()` method in `File`, which does whatever it needs to do in order to update the contents of the file.

The index position and the pointer to the `File` object is saved in the helper class, in order to make this happen. Additionally, if you still want to access the existing contents of the file, such as:

```
char c=file[10];
```

The assignment operator also implements the `char` operator. The `[]` operator passes the existing character at that position also, which gets saved in the helper class, and returned by the `char` operator.